# "Undefined control sequence" errors with moderncv (official template)

Tags: errors, moderncv

When simply trying to compile the CTAN *template.tex* available here  http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples
I receive the following errors after compiling:

```
 ! Undefined control sequence. \name
 ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help.
  etc ...
```

**EDIT**
Same problem with `\social`; `\cvcolomn`

As you can see on the website, the last update of the templates date back to 2013-04-23 08:14:47 . Since it is barely recent, I doubt that it is because of old content. Please note that I checked that package textlive-latex-extra was updated.

I have no idea why I got so much errors using some official templates.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This came up before: there was a change to the syntax I can't remember if \name was the old or new version, check the documentation for the one you have..

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Note that there is no documentation for this class yet... But the class file is well commented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\name{}{}` is the new syntax; the old syntax was `\firstname{}` and `\familyname{}`; there are also some other changes, which you can read in the [`CHANGELOG`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/CHANGELOG) file. You need to make sure that all your moderncv files are updated to 2013-04-23. Take into acount that the last update to CTAN was made when TeX Live2012 was already frozen, so perhaps the last update didn't make it to your system. You can either use the old interface, or manually install the updated versions (or perhaps try the pre-test TeX Live2013)

Comment: I see your point, and I think that you are right about the "not updated" official version. Where could I find this last package you are mentionning please? And how would you suggest me to install it on linux please? Thanks for all

Comment: @JohnDoe you can download the pre.test TeX Live2013 from [`TUG`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/pretest.html); installation instructions are available following the link I provided. Take into account, however, that the pre-test version can still contain some bugs. Instead, I would suggest you to manually download the newly updated files for `moderncv` and to work with them locally (you can simple copy-paste them to your local tree or to your current working directory).

Comment: Thats what I did, and it worked actually. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This also works for LyX users out there! Note that you have to update the package which is in /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/moderncv with the version available on http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv . Then go to Tools/Reconfigure and restart LyX.